# Como deixar uma ou mais opções pré selecionadas (ion-option)

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript

Tenho um array que preencho com dados de serviços vindos do banco de dados.
E tenho também uma tabela de relacionamento no banco entre usuário e serviço.
Eu gostaria de marcar como selecionado as opções que o usuario tiver setado no banco como prestador desse serviço.

Código que lista os serviços disponíveis que a pessoa pode prestar:

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let service of services" value={{service.id}}>{{service.description}} </ion-option>
```

Ja tenho um array com os serviços que a pessoa presta, falta só marcar no option o checked, como posso fazer isso?